# How do I change bootstrap button HTML while it is in loading mode?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap button that I need to change its TEXT to another value while the button it is in the loading state.

How do I do that?

here it is an jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/4HQ7Y/

```
$('#btn-create').click(function(){
  $('#btn-create').button("loading");
  $('#btn-create').html("Save");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#btn-create').button("reset");
  }, 2000);        
});
```

I put the button in loading mode, I change the html text but when I reset the button, the new html text goes away. I need to keep it without set after the reset because in my real project I'm using Jquery Ajax Done to set the button HTML and Jquery Ajax Always to reset the button.

The sequence should be:

Initial Text: Create

Loading Text: Creating...

Final Text: Save

What is happening?

Initial Text: Create

Loading Text: Save

Final Text: Create

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the button to "complete"?

```
$('#btn-create').click(function(){
  $('#btn-create').button("loading");
  $('#btn-create').html("Save");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#btn-create').button("complete");
  }, 2000);        
});
```

Comment: Hi Phillip, The thing is that I also NEED in a mean time, go back to the Create Text. Ex: Button html = save, then goes to loading "creating.." and then go back to Create. Using Complete does not help me :/

Comment: Hm, can you show me the part from your real project?

Comment: Basically is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Kru93/

depending of what I receive from my ajax call I will change the button HTML to Salvar or Monitorar and on always event I reset the button.

Comment: Why dont you change the text after the .button('reset') in the .always()-function?